# Will deceleration in a geostationary orbit kick me into a higher orbit?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

Lets say I am in a spaceship, and I throw a piece of space trash out the back of the spacecraft in the opposite direction from my direction of motion. The mass of the trash is small enough that it doesn't effect the orbit of my spaceship. What will happen? Will the space trash go into a higher orbit from the deceleration? or will it just  continue to orbit behind me at a slower rate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If we threw a baseball from the ISS, could we deorbit the ball?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/253944/)

Comment: No. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohmann_transfer_orbit